# How to parse data of various kinds from ajax reponse and present in UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, user-interface

Consider the following snippet with ajax call

```
var url ="/getcachevalue.do?method=getValueFromCache&key="+key.trim();
$.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : 'POST',   
        data : '',
        success : function(req){
        }
    });
```

Where the url may bring back data of any kind say

1. Number
2. Array List
3. String
4. Boolean
5. JSONObject
6. JSONArray

I have to parse the result and display it in a JSP page.

Kindly suggest me a better way to parse the response which is of any of the above kind and present the resultant values in the UI for the given input (say here my input is `key` which is passed as input to the url)

**Tried with the following:**

```
if(responsevalue.startsWith("{")) {     

  $("#resulttable").append("<tr><th>KEY </th><th>VALUE</th></tr>");  
  var result = $.parseJSON(responsevalue);
  $.each(result, function(key, value) {
    var row = ("<tr><td>").concat(key).concat("</td><td>").concat(value).concat("</td></tr>");  
    $("#resulttable").append(row);  
  });

} else {

  $("#resulttable").append("<tr><td>"+responsevalue+"</td></tr>");   
}
```

**But this produces values like**

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Have you tried any of the many JSON parsing libraries?  A raw value (e.g. `8` or `"foo"`) is, in fact, valid JSON.

Comment: What issue are you experiencing with `javascript` at Question?

Comment: No an issue, but i wish to achieve this via javascript

Comment: ie; Interpreting the response and projecting it in a better way in UI with the help of Java Script

Comment: @PaulProgrammer have edited my post with what i have tried so far.. Please make a look into it and help me to proceed further..

Comment: Is `req` always an array of values? Can you include an example of each possible response at Question?

Comment: Response is of the above quoted data types..

Comment: Say for example values of (number, boolean, string, List of strings, JSONObject ) etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()`, `typeof`, `Array.isArray()`, `Array.prototype.forEach()` to iterate arrays, `for..in` loop to iterate object properties

```js
function handleResponse(req) {

  var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req));
  // if `data` is `String`, `Number` or `Boolean` do stuff
  if (typeof data === "string" 
     || typeof data === "number" 
     || typeof data === "boolean") {
      console.log(data);
      return
  }
  // if `data` is `Array` or `Object` iterate array using `.forEach()`
  if (typeof data === "object" && Array.isArray(data)) {
    data.forEach(function(curr) {
      console.log(curr)
    })
  } 
  // else iterate object using `for..in`
  else {
    for (var prop in data) {
      console.log(prop, data[prop])
    }
  }

}

var expectedTypes = [1, "abc", true, ["abc", "def"], {abc: "def"}];

expectedTypes.forEach(handleResponse);
```

Comment: Excellent answer guest271314 ... Awesome !!